# What can I do to don't show the author name and the date into this WordPress page.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system, wordpress-theming

I am pretty new in WordPress theme development and I have the following problem.

I have this static page: http://lnx.asper-eritrea.com/lassociazione/

This is the code of my **page.php** file that render the previous static page:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying a single page
 */

get_header();
?>

<!-- Contenuti (griglia) -->
<div class="container">
<!-- Lead presentazione -->
<section id="presentazione">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<!--<h1 class="text-center"><small>Associazione per la Tutela dei Diritti Umani del Popolo Eritreo</small></h1>-->

<h1 class="text-center title">Associazione per la Tutela dei Diritti Umani del Popolo Eritreo</h1>

<p class="lead text-center">
Association in Defense of the Human Rights of the Eritrean People
</p>
</div><!-- /.col-sm-12 -->
</div><!-- /.row -->
</section><!-- /section presentazione -->

<div id="main-content" class="main-content">

<!--
<?php
if (is_front_page() && twentyfourteen_has_featured_posts()) {
    // Include the featured content template.
    get_template_part('featured-content');
}
?>
-->
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
<div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">


<?php
// Start the Loop.
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    // Include the page content template.
    get_template_part('content', 'page');

    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
    if (comments_open() || get_comments_number()) {
        comments_template();
    }
endwhile;
?>
-->

</div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<!--<?php get_sidebar('content'); ?>-->
</div><!-- #main-content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

As you can see opening the previous link in the browser under the page title are shown also the author and the date.

What can I do to don't show these informations? Can I do it from the WordPress administration panel (I can't find it) or have I to do it by code into my page.php file?

EDIT 1: This is the code of my content.php file inside my theme:

```
<?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying content
 *
 * Used for both single and index/archive/search.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage AsperTheme
 * @since AsperTheme 1.0
 */
?>


<!-- Create a div with a unique ID thanks to the_ID() and semantic classes with post_class() 
     the_ID(): Print the numeric ID of the current post 
     post_class(): Print out and add various post-related classes to the div tag
-->
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>                              

    <header>
        <h3 class="entry-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" 
                   title="<?php printf(__('Permalink to %s', 'your-theme'), the_title_attribute('echo=0')); ?>"
                   rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?>
                </a>

        </h3>

        <div class="entry-meta">
            <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-author"><?php _e('By ', 'your-theme'); ?></span>
            <span class="author vcard">
                <a class="url fn n" href="<?php echo get_author_link(false, $authordata -> ID, $authordata -> user_nicename); ?>" 
                                    title="<?php printf(__('View all posts by %s', 'your-theme'), $authordata -> display_name); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?>
                </a>
            </span>
            <span class="meta-sep"> | </span>
            <span class="meta-prep meta-prep-entry-date"><?php _e('Published ', 'your-theme'); ?></span>
            <span class="entry-date">
                <abbr class="published" title="<?php the_time('Y-m-d\TH:i:sO') ?>"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?></abbr>
            </span>
            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'your-theme' ), "<span class=\"meta-sep\">|</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"edit-link\">", "</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t" ) ?>
         </div>     <!-- .entry-meta -->

    </header>

    <div class="entry-content">    
        <?php the_content(__('Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&raquo;</span>', 'your-theme')); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages('before=<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'your-theme' ) . '&after=</div>') ?>
    </div>      <!-- .entry-content -->

    <div class="entry-utility">
        <span class="cat-links">
            <span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-cat-links"><?php _e('Posted in ', 'your-theme'); ?></span>
            <?php echo get_the_category_list(', '); ?>
        </span>
        <span class="meta-sep"> | </span>
        <?php the_tags( '<span class="tag-links"><span class="entry-utility-prep entry-utility-prep-tag-links">' . __('Tagged ', 'your-theme' ) . '</span>', ", ", "</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"meta-sep\">|</span>\n" ) ?>
            <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', 'your-theme' ), __( '1 Comment', 'your-theme' ), __( '% Comments', 'your-theme' ) ) ?></span>
            <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'your-theme' ), "<span class=\"meta-sep\">|</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class=\"edit-link\">", "</span>\n\t\t\t\t\t\n" ) ?>
    </div>      <!-- #entry-utility --> 

</article>  <!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any content-page.php in your theme directory? Reply me

Add your project in Netbeans and open the mypage.php right click near the below code

```
get_template_part('content', 'page');
```

find the function from where post content loads
Either modify the content.php or using http request uri and custom post_types , wp-query and the_content , the_title modify your template.

use if condition to check page or post like below for  tag.

```
if(!is_page( 16 )){
?><header>
//
</header><?php
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer. This is a comment. Please update it or post a comment instead.

Comment: I have not content-page.php file but I have content.php From what I have understand this content.php render the posts\pages and contains the div having class "entry-meta". So I could set it to display: none; to don't show these informations. But what have I to do if I want to show these informations for posts but not for pages?

Comment: @NithyanandhanM Ok, edited my original post. At the end of it I included the code of content.php file

Comment: @Andrea Use a condition using your page id.See the bottom of my answer.

Comment: Solved using some informations take from your post: I have create content-page.php file (that is loaded by get_template_part() into my page.php) and in this content-page.php file I don't show the author and data :-)

Answer (score 1):

Go to stili-custom.css file located in wp-content/themes/AsperTheme/assets/css/ and change this

```
.entry-meta {
font-size: 15px;
}
```

to this

```
.entry-meta {
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Andrea,

The following code should do the work. the get_template_part is where it does the trick. Or you can edit the function from the wp code, but wouldn't advice on that.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
      <ul class="articles clearfix">
        <?php
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
          printf('<li id="post-%2$s" class="article %1$s"> ',implode(' ', get_post_class()), get_the_ID() );
          get_template_part( 'template/content', 'brief' );
          echo '</li>';
          wp_reset_postdata();
        endwhile;
        ?>
      </ul>
      <?php else : ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'template/content', 'none' ); ?>
      <?php endif; ?>
```